# I'm having problems making bunnystream API requests with Vuejs fetch

Tags: vue.js, fetch, bunny

I need to send a post request to the bunnynet api using fetch in vuejs, for this I need to enter the name of the video in the body part.
I want to name the video with the variable I got from the input section, but I couldn't write it as a body. I can send requests statically, but I need to get the name of the video I will create from outside. I couldn't find a solution, I'm stuck on this, can you please help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXMn9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knaoR.png)

I tried to send the value I received as an object or as a string, unfortunately nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
body: JSON.stringify({
             // your expected POST request payload goes here
                     title: "My post title",
                     body: "My post content."
                    })
```

it worked, i'm so ignorant